# how to send message from background.js to all content script using runtime.connect

Tags: google-chrome-extension

how to send message from background.js to all content scripts using runtime.connect and 
postMessage for long lived connections.

The chrome documentation says this

```
chrome.runtime.onConnect.addListener(function(port) {
  console.assert(port.name == "knockknock");
  port.onMessage.addListener(function(msg) {
    if (msg.joke == "Knock knock")
      port.postMessage({question: "Who's there?"});
    else if (msg.answer == "Madame")
      port.postMessage({question: "Madame who?"});
    else if (msg.answer == "Madame... Bovary")
      port.postMessage({question: "I don't get it."});
  });
});
```

Will it send message to all content_script?
I read somewhere that all the content script connects to the extension through unique ports, I am just confused how to send messages to all content_script

Comment: Your example will send the response message to the (one) content script that has previously sent a message. If all content scripts connect to the background.js (even through different ports) and then send a message, background.js should respond to all those content scripts. But (of course) it won't happen with the same `postMessage` method, every content script will receive its own response

Comment: so how do i send the messages to all content scripts? should i maintain port array for content scripts and send using for loop or there is some simple way?

Comment: Yes, you should maintain an array of open ports

Answer (score 1):

As devnull69 mentioned in a comment, to send a message to all ports that have been opened you need to keep track of them.

But using an array would be a bit problematic. How do you delete a port from it that disconnected?

I found this problem interesting and wrote this code:

```js
var openPorts = ( function() {
  var index = 0;
  var ports = {};
  var op = {
    getPorts: function() {
      var result = {};
      for(var id in ports){
        result[id] = ports[id];
      }
      return result;
    },
    getPortsArray: function() {
      var result = [];
      for(var id in ports){
        result.push(ports[id]);
      }
      return result;
    },
    get: function(id) {
      return ports[id];
    },
    add: function(port) {
      var id = index;

      ports[id] = port;
      port.onDisconnect.addListener(function() {
        op.remove(id);
      });

      index++;
      return id;
    },
    remove: function(id) {
      delete ports[id];
    },
    messageAll: function(message) {
      for(var id in ports){
        ports[id].postMessage(message);
      }
    }
  };
  return op;
})();
```

This is an object that can store ports using an incremental ID like push for an array, from which they will automatically be erased as soon as their `onDisconnect` is fired.

You can potentially add a port several times, and all methods will return duplicates, but all records of the same port will be deleted since `onDisconnect` event will call all of the removal listeners. Better keep records unique though.

- `openPorts.add(port)` - function to add a port, will return its record id
  inside `openPorts`.
- `openPorts.get(id)` - function to get the Port object by a record id.
- `openPorts.remove(id)` - function to manually remove a port record by its id; will not close that port
- `openPorts.getPorts()` - returns an object with all open ports, by their record id
- `openPorts.getPortsArray()` - returns an array with all open ports, if one prefers to iterate over them.
- `openPorts.messageAll(message)` - send the same message to all ports in `openPorts`

Example usage:

```js
chrome.runtime.onConnect.addListener( function(port) { openPorts.add(port); } );

// ...

openPorts.messageAll({hello: "world"});
```